# How can I pull a specific file into the fileset?

Tags: file, clojure, boot-clj

I'm writing a library that makes use of a file from a GitHub repository that I don't own:

```sh
git init foo
cd foo
git submodule add https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Docs.git github/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Docs
mkdir -p src/com/example/foo resources/com/example/foo
```

Here are the other two relevant files in `foo`.

`build.boot`:

```
(set-env!
 :resource-paths #{"src" "resources"}
 :dependencies '[[adzerk/bootlaces "0.1.13" :scope "test"]])

(require '[adzerk.bootlaces :refer :all])

(deftask run [f function SYM sym]
  (with-pass-thru _
    (require (symbol (namespace function)))
    ((resolve function))))

(def +version+ "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT")

(bootlaces! +version+ :dont-modify-paths? true)

(task-options!
 pom {:project 'com.example/foo
      :version +version+})
```

`src/com/example/foo/core.clj`:

```
(ns com.example.foo.core
  (:require [clojure.java.io :as io]))

(defn bar []
  (some-> "com/example/foo/spec.xml" io/resource slurp count prn))
```

What I want is some sort of `add` task that allows me to do something like this:

```sh
boot add --resource --from github/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Docs/src/spec/vk.xml --to com/example/foo/spec.xml run -f com.example.foo.core/bar
```

```
585128
```

I tried using the `-R` option of [`sift`](https://github.com/boot-clj/boot/blob/master/doc/boot.task.built-in.md#sift), but it has two problems for my use case:

1. Far more files than just the one I want (`vk.xml`) are pulled into the fileset, which would bloat the size of my JAR
2. Because `-R` simply adds the directory to the set of resource paths, all of its contents are added to the fileset at the top level, which could easily clobber my own resources

Essentially, I want something that has the same effect as the below three commands, but without actually touching the `resources` directory:

```sh
cp github/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Docs/src/spec/vk.xml resources/com/example/foo/spec.xml
boot build-jar
rm resources/com/example/foo/spec.xml
```

In other words, the `com.example/foo` JAR should contain that XML file as a resource, so that resource should be available when I use `com.example/foo` from another project:

```sh
boot -d com.example/foo:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT repl
```

```
(require '[com.example.foo.core :as foo])
;;=> nil

(foo/bar)
;; 585128
;;=> nil
```

How can I pull a specific file (e.g. from a Git submodule) into the fileset at a specific location as a resource, without touching any of the files that I already have in the fileset?

Comment: can't you make just `github/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Docs/src` as resource path too?  or is there to much useless stuff?

Comment: @cfrick That has exactly the same problems as `sift -R`: JAR bloating and resource clobbering. It's not too hard to imagine a case where I would want one resource from a folder that contains tens or hundreds of megabytes of other stuff.

Comment: Did you try to use `sift -R` along with `--include` flag to specify REGEX matching your file path?

Comment: @PiotrekBzdyl That would have the same problem of clobbering existing resources, and if I'm not mistaken, the `--include` would filter out *everything* besides the one file, including all of my other resources.

Comment: @SamEstep I think you are confusing `--include` with `--invert`. Please, see my answer for the details.

Comment: You are right, it seems that `--add-resource` and `include` are separate `sift` actions and you cannot combine them to work on a single resource dir.